# Show that the function is well-defined and find its derivative and a closed form

Tags: real-analysis

> Explain why the function
>    $$f(x):=\int_0^x{\sin t \cdot \cos (xt) \over t }dt$$
>   is well-defined and compute its derivative $\;f'(x)$ in a closed form.

I am a bit confused and don't know where I should start at. Seems to me, that calculating this integral is not an option to explain that the function is well-defined.

I have tried to find its derivative using differentiation under an integral sign. However I am not sure if it is allowed, since $x$ stays not only under the integral sign, but also is an integration border.

How do I tackle the problem?

Comment: [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions $f(t)=\frac{\sin t}{t}$ and $g(t)=\cos(xt)$ are both continuous and bounded, hence $f(x)$ is a $C^1$ Lipschitz function. Moreover, you can remove the $x$ from appearing in the integral by substituting $xw$ in place of $t$:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sin(t)\cos(xt)}{t}\,dt &=& \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin(xw)\cos(x^2 w)}{w}\,dw\\ &=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin((x-x^2)w)+\sin((x+x^2)w)}{w}\,dw.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Why does the substitution yield $1$ instead of $x$ in the integral? You should also replace $t$ with $xw$ in the denominator, don't you?

Comment: If $t$ goes from $0$ to $x$, then $w=\frac{t}{x}$ goes from zero to one. It is just a change of variable.

Comment: You should replace $t$ with $xw$ and $dt$ with $x\, dw$, so the denominator stays the same.

Comment: make the substitution $u=\frac{t}{x}$ then write $t$ again in place of $u$

Comment: An interesting exercise is now to prove that $|f(x)|\leq\min\left(|x|,\frac{\pi}{2|x|^2}\right)$ and that $f(x)$ has an infinite number of real zeroes. ;)